# How to run a PowerShell script in Meson.Build?

Tags: windows, powershell, meson-build

I am trying to run a PowerShell (.ps1) script call pkg_gen.ps1 through the meson.build, but it doesn't run, the "run_target" form I am using for this code example just work with shell scripts.
This file is located in the scripts folder, and it's called using the "pkg_gen", in the script folder is another meson.build file that shows the correct path to the script.

1. meson script

```
subdir('scripts')
subdir('include')
subdir('src')
subdir('samples')
subdir('lib')

install_subdir('doc', install_dir : '.')
install_data('README', install_dir : '.')
install_data('LICENSE', install_dir : '.')
install_data('install/meson_options.txt', install_dir : '.')

run_target('package',command:[pkg_gen, python3.path()])
#run_command(pkg_gen)
```

2. scripts\meson.build

```
if is_windows
 pkg_gen = files('pkg_gen.ps1')
else
 pkg_gen = files('pkg_gen.sh')
endif 
wheel_gen = files('wheel_gen.py')
```

If someone knows how to run a powershell script, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this should work

```
package_cmd = [pkg_gen, python3.path()]
run_target('package',command:['powershell'] + package_cmd)
```

Big thanks to my coworker Vitaut.